# Creating a Circuit with Resistors Given the Total Resistance

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

How can I create a circuit with a total resistance of 144.7 ohm which is composed of 10-ohm resistors? How many parallel and/or series resistors should it contain?

I've tried solving this but the nearest total resistance to 144.7 ohm that I get is 144 ohm exactly. Actually, this isn't for real-life usage rather just a circuit analysis problem. Please help.

Comment: Given that fixed value resistors come with a tolerance its impossible to get an exact value - why not just use a preset variable resistor (say 10 turn 220R)

Comment: Please edit your question to explain _why_ you want to do this and what accuracy you require.

Comment: This question seems a bit unclear. However I would suggest why don't you use some series or parallel combination of resistors to get to the desired value.

Comment: 100 10-ohm resistors in parallel is 0.1 ohms. 7 such combinations in series is 0.7 ohms. So there is at least one solution to add the 0.7 ohms to your 144 ohms. Whether that's practical depends on information you're not sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/does-anyone-remember-this-article-about-the-euclidean-algorithm) useful.

It shows how to use the method of continued fractions to create a resistance by combining a number of same-value resistors.